# To send string directly to web console using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So, currently, I'm trying to use Selenium to send a string directly chrome console, because I need to activate a specific command. I was looking around, and didn't find very much on the topic--at-least that was related to what I was trying to do. So I had two question. Is it possible/how to do it with Selenium, and it it's not, or if there is a better library to do this with use what would it be?

What I'm trying to use is:

```
driver.execute_script(console.log('String))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple! I didn't need console.log, it was just:

'''
driver.execute_script('String')
'''